# How to convert day of week from Sunday first to Monday first in c++?

Tags: c++, date, arduino, dayofweek

I have a function which returns the day of week as an integer, Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc. to 6. I want to convert this to Monday = 0, ..., Sunday = 6. I can not think of better way than the one listed below, but it is clumsy. Is there a better way?

```
if (!currTime.dayOfTheWeek()) { // if time.dow == 0
    dayOfWeek = 6;
}
  else {
    dayOfWeek = currTime.dayOfTheWeek() - 1;
}
```

by the way, this is Arduino code, using RTCLib for time.

Comment: That's probably the simplest and most understandable way to handle it. There are other ways, but they will not be as simple or readable.

Comment: As a general tip: Don't be clever! Cleverness tend to create code that is highly unreadable, and therefore hard to impossible to understand and maintain. Strive primarily for simplicity and readable code, and let the compiler handle the cleverness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative:

To map 0...6 from [Sun. to Sat.] to [Mon. to Sun.]

```
dayOfWeek_fromMonday = (dayOfWeek_fromSunday + 6)%7;
```

---

Say you wanted to start on Wednesday (something more interesting that a shift by 1) rather than Sunday and avoid naked magic numbers.

```
#define DaysWedToSun 4
#define DaysPerWeek 7 
dayOfWeek_fromWed = (dayOfWeek_fromSun + DaysWedToSun)%DaysPerWeek;
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple. What are the rules? If the day is Sunday(0) we change it to 6, all others we subtract one.

```
int dayOfWeek = ..;
dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek == 0 ? 6 : dayOfWeek - 1;
```